# How to get Sonar-java issue present in many files?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to use the source code of [sonar-java](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java) to identify sonarbugs in isolated files instead of projects. How can I get an issue as an `AnalyzerMessage` when it spans two files, like the issue of non-serializable superclass not having no argument constructor?

**Edit :** I am using JavaCheckVerifier.verify() and MultipleFilesJavaCheckVerifier.verify() to check issues, but they only verify issues present in a single file. When an issue has parts in multiple files, it doesn't verify it.

Comment: please add your code and error to the question

Comment: I don't have an error. I have added the problem in the edit.